# How to play RTMP video streaming in ios app?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller, rtmp, broadcasting

HI I'm developing Broadcast App for that I'm using Videocore library now how can i play that streaming video in ios app i tried with the MpMoviePlayer but it won't support the rtmp stream. so is there any third party libraries available for RTMP supported Players please help me

Comment: Care to share any progress you've made with this?

Comment: I am using VLC player for playing rtmp streaming videos.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were trying to playback RTMP within the app.

Comment: yes now it is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the `RTMP` live stream ready and playing as HLS then you can simply add `.m3u8` after the stream name and make `RTMP` link to `http`. For example you have `RTMP` link like this:

> `rtmp://XY.Y.ZX.Z/hls/chid`

You have to just make the url like this:

> `http://XY.Y.ZX.Z/hls/chid.m3u8`

and it will play smoothly in iOS. I have tried following code and it is working fine.

```
func setPlayer()
{
    // RTMP URL rtmp://XY.Y.ZX.Z/hls/chid be transcripted like this http://XY.Y.ZX.Z/hls/chid.m3u8 it will play normally.

    let videoURL = URL(string: "http://XY.Y.ZX.Z/hls/chid.m3u8")

    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: videoURL!)
    let adID = AVMetadataItem.identifier(forKey: "X-TITLE", keySpace: .hlsDateRange)
    let metadataCollector = AVPlayerItemMetadataCollector(identifiers: [adID!.rawValue], classifyingLabels: nil)
    //metadataCollector.setDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
    playerItem.add(metadataCollector)


    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    self.player = player
    player.play()
}
```

But it will be slow and laggy because of the high resolution video stream upload. If you make the resolution to low when uploading the video stream, it will work smooth in low bandwidth network as well.